# Projectile session/state

Tags: projectile, doom

Initially I scanned the user directory (`~`) for projects, through inexperience. Later I defined the project root (`~/.doom.d/config.el`):

```
;; Projectile settings.
(setq projectile-project-search-path
      '("~/spaces/")
      projectile-sort-order 'recentf)
```

Unfortunately, `M-x projectile-discover-projects-in-search-path` won't update anything; I still got one great user-wide project. Probably, I have to delete file or files where the relevant state is saved, but I have no idea where to look for these files.

*NB* On another box, where `projectile-project-search-path` was set from the beginning, the situation is normal.

My questions: (1) what are the files where the projectile info is saved (2) how to put things to rights by deleting these files or otherwise.

UPD

`M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` does not make any difference.

Comment: What's your *question*?

Comment: My questions: (1) what are the files where the projectile info is saved (2) how to put things to  rights by deleting these files *or otherwise*.

Comment: I copied the comment to the body of your question, but in the future please don't add vital information as a comment: add it directly to the question. Thanks!